# How to properly copy files from hard drive to USB flash drive in tty4 terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, kernel, usb-drive, tty

How to properly copy files from hard drive to USB flash drive in tty4 terminal?(mount, copy, unmount, exit, etc)

P.S.Can no exit from tty4 terminal via `Ctrl+Alt+F7` command, only with `Alt+SysRq+B`(kernel restart).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Plug in the device
2. `lsblk` to find the device name of your usb device. Naming is `/dev/sdXY`. Where X is any english letter and Y is integer, typically 1.

If the device was mounted, you will see the mountpoint, for example:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb            8:0    1 15.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1         8:1    1 15.2G  0 part /media/me/4C45-110F
```

If not, mount it. Follow to the step #3

3. `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdXY` , device name same as in previous step. (`/dev/sdb1` in my example) The mount folder will be reported back to you to use in the next step. For example, suppose `lsblk` tells me this:

   sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk 
   └─sdc1   8:33   1   7.5G  0 part

Then I will do the following:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc1                                                 
Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/xieerqi/A669-34EF.
```

You can see it automatically created `/media/xieerqi/A669-34EF` folder and mounted my pen drive there. Also , big advantage is that you do not need `sudo`.

4. Use `rsync` or `cp` or `mv` to get your files to the folder reported in step 3. Consult manual pages on usage of these commands. `cp` and `mv` are simplest. `mv FILE DESTINATION` - in my example 
   (where FILE is the thing you want to move to the drive)

   ```
   mv FILE /media/me/4C45-110F
   ```

`rsync` is the best for backup however.

For example, to backup `TESTDIR` to my usb drive, I can do this:

```
$ rsync -av /home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/ /media/xieerqi/A669-34EF/~                  
sending incremental file list
created directory /media/xieerqi/A669-34EF/~
./
file1
file2
file3

sent 228 bytes  received 125 bytes  706.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

5. `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdXY`. Remove the device

Example

```
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc1
Unmounted /dev/sdc1.
```

**NOTE**: some drives mount to directories that have names with spaces. If you run `rsync` or `mv` with not quoted names like that, **your data will not be copied to correct destination**. Always quote pathnames that have spaces in them.

Comment: What is purpose of `udisksctl` command? I just saw several examples without `udisksctl`. Also, what is `-b` option?

Comment: `udisksctl` is part of `udisks` package, and comes by default with Ubuntu.  Basically , it's a utility for doing all the basic actions like mounting , unmounting , checking info about a disk, but without need for running `sudo`. Such utilities as `mount` require superuser privilleges to work. `-b` option stands for `block-device`, which is what `/dev/sdXY` is classified as. Every hard-drive or usb drive is classified as block device

Comment: No need to use` sudo mkdir /media/usbstick ` command before mounting? Some manuals use this command.

Comment: @minto  `udisksctl` does it automatically for you.  I will be adding more examples later, so you will  see how it works

Comment: One important note:  if USB stick inserted into USB port, it already mounted , I assume.  Command `lsblk` show  sdb -> sdb1. In this case, if I run `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1`, it return error  `"device already mounted..."`

Comment: @minto It will not necessarily   be mounted . Conveniently , if you're running Unity session, there is a daemon ( aka service ) in place that automounts USB devices. If you're running something like `openbox` or `blackbox`  desktop , that service probably won't start  , therefore you will need to mount manually.

Comment: Using rsync seemed to throw (error 23), it didn't copy hidden files and git-related.files from what --progress showed. This is due to permission denial..but couldn't find an answer of how to resolve this.

Comment: For some reason the `udisksctl`command asked password when mounting. I was using ssh connection to a host.

Answer (score 13):

In my case the above answer was no working so i tried this.
My system config is Ubuntu 14.04, while updating to 16.06 LTS, suddenly it stopped to work so to copy my important files , I used my pen-drive to copy.

**1. List the Mount device:**

```
lsblk
```

**2. Create a mount point :**

This needs to be mounted into the filesystem somewhere. You can usually use /mnt/ if you're being lazy and nothing else is mounted there but otherwise you'll want to create a new directory:

```
sudo  mkdir /media/usb
```

**3. Mount!**

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

**4. Copy**

```
 rsync -av /home/android/Testproject/ /media/usb/
```

**5.Un-Mount**
*When you're done, just fire off:*

```
sudo umount /media/usb
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!
But as I wanted to copy the files that are on my USB I did sth like this  instead `rsync -av /media/usb/ /home/android/Testproject/`